# Customize the django User management

Tags: django, django-admin

By default, I can see "Delete the selected user" action from django user admin page, now I want to add more actions? Who has any idea?

I've looked at "http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#writing-actions", but I don't know how to add the action to it. Need your help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want actions to be added to the User model, w/o changing the Django code you need: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#making-actions-available-site-wide
Example usage case: custom .delete() methods.